# Generic Windows 7 Drivers for ATI FireMV 2250?

Tags: windows-7, video, drivers, 64-bit

I have contacted ATI but have gotten no response. I recently upgraded to WIndows 7 and now my multiple monitors are not working because there is no driver available for my secondary video card. I see the card listed as "ATI FireMV 2250 (Microsoft Corporation WDDM)" with an exclamation point in Device Mgr.

I tried the Vista x64 driver for the card but was met with an error message during installation that I was using an incompatible OS.

I don't need any special functionality other than the ability to display 1280x1024 on a monitor attached to this card. Is there a generic driver I could use for this card? (alternate 2nd question: Is there any hope of ATI releasing a 64-bit Windows 7 driver for this card?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 'brute force' instead of the ATI installer?

Extract the Vista x64 driver (e.g. with [Unviersal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)) and then install it manually via the device manager, ignoring all warnings about uncertified drivers.

*Note: you should make a drive image before 'pulling such stunts'!*

Edit: by 'brute force' i meant manual driver installation (Let me pick > Have Disk)

[image]

[image]

Comment: A *super* idea... I was not aware of Universal Extractor (that gets a point just for the sheer helpfulness for all kinds of driver installation woes :)

But alas, when pointing to the extracted inf I am met with a msg: "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, Make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems."

p.s. Fortunately this is a very fresh Win7 install - the only thing installed thus far is FireFox, so I don;t mind if I hos the system- it's worth it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a number of different approaches here... an interesting point I neglected to mention initially- When I booted into Win 7 for the very first time, there was video on my third display. After a minute or so, it shut off apparently due to a driver issue.

Today I reset the driver to the Standard VGA driver and rebooted. No luck. But then I installed the same driver that was initially not working (Win 7 WDDM driver) and - wtf - it's working now. Let's hope for more than just a few minutes!

(this is actually Phatteus... my accts are screwy on this new OS installation)

**THIS POST HAS BEEN ANSWERED - I AM NO LONGER LOOKING FOR A SOLUTION**

(though add'l comments are always welcome ;)

Comment: You should edit your post, rather than add an answer, and you should indicate that you're not longer looking for a solution.

Comment: I *can't* edit my post- that is the issue... I can't seem to "be" Phatteus :)